# First time chaining functions

Tags: go, chaining

Suppose I want to run a logger before I run my custom mux for http server.

Part way there I can chain loggers and add a custom mux like this: https://play.golang.org/p/Edurl-Rhqb9

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

type Middleware func(http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc

func ServeHTTPIterator(h http.HandlerFunc, m ...Middleware) http.HandlerFunc {
    if len(m) < 1 {
        return h
    }
    wrapped := h

    // loop in reverse to preserve middleware order
    for i := len(m) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        wrapped = m[i](wrapped)
    }
    return wrapped
}

func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello Index!")
}

func LogFirst(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Print(`First`)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func LogSecond(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Print(`Second`)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    httpServer := &http.Server{
        Addr:         `my.local:8080`,
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
    }

    var Router *httprouter.Router

    preMiddle := []Middleware{
        LogFirst,
        LogSecond,
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", ServeHTTPIterator(IndexHandler, preMiddle...))

    httpServer.Handler = Router
}
```

But now let suppose I wanted to run my mux after the loggers, in that case I figured I would do something like:

```
    preMiddle := []Middleware{
        LogFirst,
        LogSecond,
        Router,
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to wrap Router to make this work or if this is even a legitimate approach. Could someone clue me in on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code to work with http.Handler instead of http.HandlerFunc.

```
type Middleware func(http.Handler) http.Handler

func ServeHTTPIterator(h http.Handler, m ...Middleware) http.Handler {
    if len(m) < 1 {
        return h
    }
    wrapped := h

    // loop in reverse to preserve middleware order
    for i := len(m) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        wrapped = m[i](wrapped)
    }
    return wrapped
}
    
func LogFirst(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Print(`First`)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func LogSecond(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Print(`Second`)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Create the router and register the handler with the router. Add parameters argument to IndexHandler so that the function is compatible with httprouter.

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.GET("/", IndexHandler)
```

Wrap the router using the new version of ServeHTTPIterator.

```
httpServer.Handler = ServeHTTPIterator(router, preMiddle...)
```

With these changes, the logs are written before the router is called.

Comment: With this part `http.Handle("/", ...` Doesn't `http.Handle` only act on the default mux and if that's the case is there any value in this line since we are ultimately replacing the default mux with httprouter when we do `httpServer.Handler = ...`?

Comment: I appreciate that and sorry for bring up one other question but I am using a custom router `httprouter` (see at top) so `router := http.NewServeMux()` doesn't really apply in this case unless the code comes out identical I guess.

Comment: "The code in the question does not use httprouter" - Huh? `var Router *httprouter.Router` & `"github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"` & `httpServer.Handler = Router` are right there in the code, but if you made the changes no matter.

Comment: The application in the question does use a nil pointer to an httprouter, but the application does not create an httprouter or register handlers with an httprouter.

Comment: True, it is just a code snippet and not a full application and if I thought putting more in would have been necessary to be clear enough I would have... it's not always possible to know how much is enough vs how much is just adding noise that is distracting from the question at hand.

Comment: Let me know if I put this all together correctly, I get this code: https://play.golang.org/p/xFJFu0X_Dow

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by, instead of spreading the middlewares in your serveIterator func expect an slice of middlewares to be applied like: [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ey3e07s2M2O)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

type Middleware func(http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc

func ServeHTTPIterator(h http.HandlerFunc, m []Middleware) http.HandlerFunc {
    if len(m) < 1 {
        return h
    }
    wrapped := h

    // loop in reverse to preserve middleware order
    for i := len(m) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        wrapped = m[i](wrapped)
    }
    return wrapped
}

func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello Index!")
}

func LogFirst(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Print(`First`)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func LogSecond(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Print(`Second`)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    httpServer := &http.Server{
        Addr:         `my.local:8080`,
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
    }

    var Router *httprouter.Router
    
    preMiddle := []Middleware{
        LogFirst,
        LogSecond,
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", ServeHTTPIterator(IndexHandler, preMiddle))

    httpServer.Handler = Router
}
```

Comment: FYI: I would have preferred to split this between both of these answers as both are equally valid. I only favored the other one because of preference of coding style.

Comment: no issues, I got to learn that approach as well